# Mercado Pago Client onPaymentMethodsRecieved

Tags: mercadopago, mercadopagosdk

I am trying to integrate Mercado Pago to my React aplication, first I want to connect the client so I can set up some alerts (/process-payments is going to be done through python)

I am having a problem. I can not log PaymentMethods nor Issuers. Strangely my issuers field is populated. For example whenever I put a random card Number I get logged the installments yet not the issuers (although I can see them)

[Console and Product image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rias.png)

The following is my code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
if (MercadoPago) {
  const mp = new MercadoPago(
    PUBLIC_KEY
  );
  console.log("mp es", mp);
  const cardForm = mp.cardForm({
    amount: "200",
    autoMount: true,
    form: formConfig,
    callbacks: {
      onFormMounted: (error) => {
        if (error) {
          return console.warn("Form mounted handling error: ", error);
        }
        console.log("Form Mounted");
      },
      onPaymentMethodsRecieved: (error, paymentMethods) => {
        console.log("In Payment methods");
        if (error) {
          window.alert("No payment methods");
        }
        console.log("Payment Methods Available", paymentMethods);
      },
      onIssuersRecieved: (error, issuers) => {
        if (error) return console.warn("issuers handling error: ", error);
        console.log("Issuers available: ", issuers);
      },
      onInstallmentsReceived: (error, installments) => {
        if (error)
          return console.warn("installments handling error: ", error);
        console.log("Installments available: ", installments);
      },
      onCardTokenRecieved: (error, token) => {
        if (error) {
          return console.warn("Token no se pudo crear: ", error);
        }
        console.log("Token available: ", token);
      },.......}
```

Comment: Please your code in the question itself as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misspelled 'onPaymentMethodsRec**ie**ved', it should be onPaymentMethodsRec**ei**ved. The same happens in the others logs.